# will python script running inside a kubernetes pod exit if my laptop/system turned off

Tags: python, bash, kubernetes, exit

I am running a python script inside a kubernetes pod with kubectl exec -it  bash.Its a long running script which might take a day to complete.i executed the python script from my laptop inside the kubernetes pod.
If i close my laptop,will the script stop running inside the pod?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Kubernetes on Cloud, the script will continue until it is finished succefully or throws an error even if you close your laptop,

Othewise, if you are running local Kubernetes Cluster, for example: with `minikube`, cluster will shut down and so is your script

Comment: Thank you .i gained access to kubernetes cluster using the kubeconfig file of staging environment and then ran the script inside the pod.My terminal on laptop MAC will exit to outer shell from kubectl exec right but wont stop the script from running right if the laptop is in sleep mode or shut down?Could you please clarify

Comment: Where is hosted your K8s cluster? @SubhamDas

Comment: On staging environment

Comment: And where is that? Cloud or local

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to know the answer without at least the following information:

- laptop OS (including distribution and version)
- whether your k8s is running directly on your laptop or on remote hardware

I'll assume you're running linux. If you are running a productive k8s locally on your laptop (in which case, why?), then you likely have to change the settings in your desktop environment, or temporarily disable acpid, or your virtualised cluster will cease to exist when the power turns off. All of the former is completely dependent on your hardware and software.

If the process is running remotely (on other hardware), turning off your laptop will not make a difference to the running script. Read the [man page](https://manpages.org/kubectl-exec/1) for kubectl-exec:

```
-i, --stdin=false
    Pass stdin to the container

-t, --tty=false
    Stdin is a TTY
```

The arguments for an interactive shell are just about mapping stdin to the container; kubectl won't kill your remote process if your laptop turns off, loses network connectivity etc.

Comment: I am using the kubeconfig file of staging environment and executed the script inside the pod.In that case,if i shut down my laptop or put my laptop in sleep mode,if i login to the pod again,will it still show the script running or it would have exited?

Comment: Please answer the questions in my answer, else I can't answer your question. What laptop OS are you using (including distribution and version)? Is your kubernetes cluster running locally on your laptop or on remote hardware?

Comment: MacOS Big Sur 11.6.8 (20G730).I am login in to the pod in staging environment using the kubeconfig file (to get access to staging kubernetes cluster)

Comment: As you mention a staging environment, I assume this is a remote cluster (running on server hardware that is not your laptop). In that case, close your laptop; the script will keep running on the cluster  :)